# Content for slides of theoretical project

Tags: presentation

I was assigned a project of reading a unit of a textbook for 3 months and I need to present it by making a project report.

Since my mentor didn't ask for any hands-on, I just studied the particular unit in the textbook.

Now, I need to present my report. I am thinking of placing key theorem statements and results from that unit and explain them. Note that all of the members of the panel know that unit very well. But I'm confused yet because if I place all the statements, I can get very few slides(at most 3) and faculty may feel that I did very little work in 3 months. My colleagues are presenting their code and output screenshots etc., instead of theoretical since they did the implementation project.

So what are the contents I need to keep in my report presentation?

Comment: What does your mentor advise?

Comment: I didn't submit to him yet for signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, most slide-based presentations have too many slides, not too few. It is very difficult to find a good balance. Of course, it depends on the time set aside for your talk. If it is 20 minutes or so, you may already be fine.

However, an additional slide for each Theorem giving the key ideas from the proof might be useful. It could be a sparse proof outline, or just a statement of what earlier work contributes to the proof.

However, since it sounds like you fellow students have done things that are based on this chapter of the book, it might be even more useful to say something about *how* this work leads to the more practical things. In other words, not just *what* are the important theorems, but *why* they are important to the work that follows. In other words, place that chapter in the context of the larger goals of the group. That will let you add a bit to your presentation and, perhaps, make it more useful.